# Can I use Bootstrap's Carousel a simple Gallery (no links)?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, carousel

According to the explanations, yes. My problem is, every click to the NEXT-Button will cause the browser to navigate to the default page.

[image: Demonstration of the Effect]

I've copied the excapt examples from getbootrap and mdbootstrap (shown below) where I still have this problem.

```
  <div class="row">
    <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(45).jpg"
            alt="First slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(46).jpg"
            alt="Second slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(47).jpg"
            alt="Third slide">
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Clicking on the NEXT link will start navigation to http://localhost:4200/login#carouselExampleControls
(login is my "dafault" page)

The carousel and it's surrounding row is embbedded in an ng-container (to handle an asyncpipe)

I'm not sure if it's got to do with my routing or just the sample link. If i remove the links, there will be no action at all of course.

As mentioned above, I dont to navigate away from that page. I just want to show the images and let the user browse the "gallery"

**UPDATE**
I suspect the redirection, but couldn't fix it when removed.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'login', // später evtl. auf home
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'register',
    component: RegisterComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'course/:courseId',
    component: CourseComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard]
  }
];
```

Comment: If you want to add your real site link, don't use the localhost because it always refers to your local files. You should include a Codepen example (or similar) or link to a live site that is already hosted on your server.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably in the loading order of your script. 
If you have [jQuery](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.0/jquery.min.js) scripts and [Bootstrap](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js) scripts included, you should load jQuery first.

Comment: There's no jQuery. I suspect routing. Also I've swtiched to ng-bootstrap now, no effect